# Netbeans 8.1 IDE exits unexpectedly on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: netbeans, ubuntu-17.04

I am using Ubuntu 17.04 as my OS. I want to install and use Netbeans as my php editor. So I have tried `sudo apt install netbeans` and Netbeans 8.1 is now installed on my system.

But as I try to open it, it gets closed just after trying to open. Even using sudo command (`sudo netbeans`) or not (as normal user).

[image: before]

[image: after]

I have tested to run app from terminal but no errors outputted (as can be seen in above image).

### Update

The message.log that is asked in comment is this:

> ---
>
> ...
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- java.lang.SecurityException: setContextClassLoader    at
>   java.base/jdk.internal.misc.InnocuousThread.setContextClassLoader(InnocuousThread.java:104)
>     at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.updateContextClassLoaders(Unknown
>   Source)   at org.netbeans.ModuleManager.(Unknown Source)    at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.ModuleSystem.(Unknown Source)     at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.getModuleSystem(Unknown Source) INFO
>   [null]: Last record repeated again.   at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.Main.start(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.netbeans.core.startup.TopThreadGroup.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)

Screen Shot:

[image: screen shot of messages.log]

According to [this bug report](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=258808) it seems that, this issue is fixed on netbeans 8.2 but by now it is not available. Any idea?

Comment: You'll find the IDE's logfile in `~/.netbeans/8.2/var/log`. It is called `messages.log`. Please post.

Comment: @peterh, I've added info. please check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You combo is not supported.

You are using Java 9 with NetBeans 8.1. That won't fly.

First of all:  Why use an old version of NetBeans. Why not use NetBeans 8.2?

Secondly: Using Java 9 as the runtime for *executing* NetBeans will not be supported until NetBeans 9.x is released.

Solution:

- Use Java 8, not Java 9. You can use a private copy of Java only for NetBeans, if you don't want to change you system's overall Java. This is done by setting `netbeans_jdkhome` variable in `/usr/share/netbeans/8.x/etc/netbeans.conf` file.
- Use NetBeans 8.2  (just because it is always best to use the latest. NB 8.1 was released in Oct 2015, almost 2 years ago, while NB 8.2 was released last October).

If you still have problems after this then please post here.